# Sinon.js: How to mock a object constructed with new?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I have this code:

```
var async = require('async'),
    util = require('util');

var Parse = require('parse/node');

function signup(userInfo, callback) {
    var username = userInfo.username,
        email = userInfo.email,
        password = userInfo.password;

    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set('username', username);
    user.set('email', email);
    user.set('password', password);

    user.signUp(null, {
        success: (user) => {
            // console.log('BaaS Signup success ' + util.inspect(user));
            callback(null, user);
        },
        error: (user, error) => {
            // console.log('BaaS Signup error ' + util.inspect(error));
            callback(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

I want to unit test it, and as such need to be able to test the content of the success and error function.

If user was a library, I could use proxyquire and put a stub returning a promise and be done with it, however, user is constructed.

How can I stub `Parse.User()` so that I can control the resulting object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is ugly as hell, I ve succeed in making my test work with this:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    util = require('util');

var proxyquire =  require('proxyquire').noPreserveCache();
var sinon = require('sinon');


describe('SignUp', () => {
        it('Expect to sign up the user and return the user', (done) => {
            var stub = {
                    parse: {
                        User: function User() {
                            this.set = () => {};
                            this.signUp = (a, c) => {
                                c.success({id: 'UserID'});
                            };
                        }
                    }
                },
                baas = proxyquire('./../baas.js', {
                    'parse/node': stub.parse
                });

            baas.signup({
                username: 'User',
                email: 'user@test.com',
                password: 'Password'
            }, (err, user) => {
                try {
                    expect(err).to.not.be.ok;
                    expect(user).to.be.ok;
                    done();
                } catch(err) {
                    done(err);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

The answer I received made me realize I don't use sinon like I should, and all my test are built by hacking around part of proxyquire and sinon together.

I will need to reread the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
// test `success` callback
let testUser = { user : 'test' };
let stub     = sinon.stub(Parse.User.prototype, 'signUp')
                    .yieldsTo('success', testUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to stub the constructor just like you'd stub any other funtion, and just return your fake object:

```
sinon.stub(Parse, "User")
    .andReturn(fakeUser);

let u = new Parse.User();
//u === fakeUser
```